# JQuery Accordion - Opening issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a vertical accordion which opens perfectly fine when starting to open the accorion from the top down but if you pick one of the options in the middle of the accordion 1st then it does not open correctly.

Oddly, if I open the 1st option then collapse it I can open any other option with no issue.

I'm not sure I've explained this too well so here's a fiddle showing the issue, occurs in both Chrome & IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/gstubbenhagen/JyFRC/

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It was doing weird stuff for me so I wacked out ALL the css you had and it works OK, though not so pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the whole UI library for just an accordion?

## *[Demo without the jQuery.UI](http://jsfiddle.net/JyFRC/2/)*

```
$('#accordion > h2').click(function(){
   var el = $(this).next('.pane');
    el.is(':hidden') ? ($('.pane').slideUp(), el.slideDown()) : $('.pane').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Lighter is always better

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is caused by your `display: none` call on #accordion .pane. I am assuming you want to have all of the panels hidden when the user loads the page?

Eliminate the `display: none` and instead use `active: false` as an option for the accordion:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Setting "active" to false collapses all panes on loading.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active